# CCapture.js webm video blacked out

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, video-capture, webm

I've been trying to record a video of an HTML Canvas animation using the [CCapture.js](https://github.com/spite/ccapture.js/) project. Specifically, it has a webm capture option which uses [whammy.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy) under the hood. I've tinkered with many of the parameters, but so far I've only had it output a video of the correct length, but without any of the canvas elements - it just looks black.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ethmy2po/4/) illustrating the issue. It creates an animation and records 2 seconds, then saves/downloads the webm output.

Here is the CCapture setup I've got in the jsfiddle:

```
capturer = new CCapture({
  display: true,
  framerate: 30,
  format: 'webm',
  verbose: true,
});

// start capture
capturer.start();

// end capture and save
setTimeout(function() {
  capturer.stop();
  capturer.save();
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was a [bug in Whammy.js](https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy/issues/43), an [issue with parsing webp](https://github.com/chrahunt/TagProReplays/commit/0468714cc445cf7875b52b459682f4392c2ef98e#diff-e86e17cf209c8a7f8d42905e3990ce2cR157). After applying the fix, it is recording correctly again!